# Why does BERT has a limitation of only allowing the maximum length of the input tokens as 512?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, word-embeddings

I have seen BERT was one of the state-of-the-arts word embedding method in 2018 and then XLNet is proposed in 2019 to take care of the limitations of BERT. I have seen one limitation of BERT is the the maximum length of input tokens (which is 512, see [this link](https://medium.com/dataseries/why-does-xlnet-outperform-bert-da98a8503d5b#:~:text=al.%2C%202019)-,Absorbing%20Transformer-XL,supports%20up%20to%20512%20token) ). Does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an arbitrary value. It is the longest length of input vector they assumed to be possible. Presumably, they didn't have longer vectors in the training set. Moreover, you can always truncate a vector and ignore farther away history, so in such case the length of the vector would be the farthest history you would considered to be useful. 512 is a power of two, what also suggests that the value is chosen arbitrarily by a computer science minded person.

Comment: (+1) 512 might not be *totally arbitrary* — for instance, this value could have a certain importance if the software used for Bert hits a performance cliff at 513, perhaps due to upstream choices made by the programmer or even the compiler.

Comment: @Sycorax yeah, that's likely. Another hypothesis is that this fitted the memory, or was more cost-efficient for other reasons. But from the point of the model behind it, it is an arbitrary value that does not have any deeper meaning.

Comment: Yep, 512 being a good choice for arranging the data in GPU memory is a plausible hypothesis — and you're correct that the arcana of GPU memory or compiler logic has no bearing on the task of embedding natural language.